# Clean Ransack search URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, clean-urls, search-form

How do I get a clean URL after searching through a Ransack form?

**Current URL**

```
www.abc.com/family/dashboard?utf8=✓&q%5Bnannies_gender_eq%5D=&q%5Bhourly_rate_start_gteq%5D=&q%5Bhourly_rate_end_lteq%5D=&q%5Bnannies_hours_gteq%5D=&q%5Bnannies_sunday_eq%5D=&q%5Bnannies_monday_true%5D=1&q%5Bnannies_tuesday_true%5D=1&q%5Bnannies_sunday_true%5D=1&commit=Search
```

Need a clean URL like, no matter what the parameters are.

```
www.abc.com/family/dashboard
```

Is it a Rails thing or a Ransack thing? Or web dev in general?

Comment: Try changing the controller action to `post` action from `get` action in `routes.rb`

Comment: You can implement search using AJAX, so current URL will not change at all.